# How to execute a program as variable in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am writing a program with two inputs prog1 and prog2 which are both files. I save these two variables as program1 and program2 first and then execute these two files in my program using ./"$program1" and ./"program2", but the output is "No such file or directory" when i used ls to check the files are in the same directory as the script. Can anyone tell me how to execute it? thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you have not made the files that are held in `program1` and `program2` executable, e.g. `chmod +x filename1 filename2`

Comment: Also, if it's not a typo, your ./"program2" is missing a "$". One thing you can try is to echo the variable to make sure it contains what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing it as ./$prog1 execute it as below.

```sh
bash $prog1
bash $prog2
```

where $prog1 and $prog2 are variables which have the path of the bash scripts.

Comment: `./$prog1`, etc.. would work fine so long as the file referenced by the variable had the *execute* permission bit set for the user running the original script. You approach will work as well,, depends on what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems like your brackets are out of place - ./"$program1" is not a valid expression, either loose the brackets or put it like this: "./$program1".

Then to elaborate a bit on David's comment:

There are two ways you can run another script from your script. One is to make them executable like David said.

However, you can also use the 'source' command to read and execute the content of files, even if they are not executable. So the following command would work in any case:

source "./$program1"